# How to convert from json map

Tags: java, json

I am having a json string like this

```
{  
   "999999999":"{"   
          CustomerVO   {  
                  username='Ashwin',
                  password='12345',
                  confirmpassword='12345',
                  mobilenumber='1010121214',
                  emailid='addsd@g.c',
                  address='kanpur',
                  pincode='741025'
           }"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
JSON.parse(object);
```

Where object is your json string. A detailed example can be found here:
[Mozilla Developer Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 0):

You can use google API `gson` parser

e.g

```
JsonObject jobj = new Gson().fromJson(response, JsonObject.class);
jsonresponse = jobj.get("status").getAsString();
```